# Hashmap size is not constant

Tags: android, mysql, hashmap

I want to retrieve values from a Hash map. When i tried to display the size of a Hashmap in a TextView the size changes in my screen. Any ideas why?
Is there any other way instead of using Hashmap to store the JSONArray so it is more easy to retrieve values?

```
public void updateJSONdata() {
  cafebartablesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();
  JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
  JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);

  try {
    cafebartables = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < cafebartables.length(); i++) {
      LoadMap ld = new LoadMap();
      ld.execute();
      JSONObject c =cafebartables.getJSONObject(i);

      int tableId = c.getInt(TAG_TABLE_ID);
      int tableMarginLeft = c.getInt(TAG_MARGIN_LEFT);
      int tableMarginTop = c.getInt(TAG_MARGIN_TOP);
      int isFree = c.getInt(TAG_ISFREE);

      map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
      map.put(TAG_TABLE_ID, tableId);
      map.put(TAG_MARGIN_LEFT, tableMarginLeft);
      map.put(TAG_MARGIN_TOP, tableMarginTop);
      map.put(TAG_ISFREE, isFree);

      cafebartablesList.add(map);
    }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public  void printMap() {
  mapcounter ++;
  length_txt =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.length_txt);
  length_txt.setText("the size is " +cafebartablesList.size());
}

public class LoadMap extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
  @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
      updateJSONdata();
      return null;
    }

  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      printMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're displaying the size of the list, which is how many hash maps you have, not how many elements are in the hash map.

Comment: Having trouble understanding your code. You recursively call your updateJSONdata code inside an asynctask?
Have you tried using gson with a typeadapter instead?

Comment: In which way i can display the number of elements  Hashmap contains and retrieve it one by one?

Comment: @hhoang i am new to android i haven't use gson.

Comment: You don't really need gson i guess, I think the problem is how you're executing your asynctask. You're rebuilding your map several times depending on the size of your cafebartables size. Just execute your asynctask once from inside your print method, and have it update your views once it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're method is executing an asynctask that's recursively calling itself, which is probably causing some weird behavior.

Try something like this instead. have your print method call your asynctask. Your asynctask calls updateJSONdata, which iterates over the json object and constructs your map. At the end of your asynctask, update your textview with the size of your map.

```
public void updateJSONdata() {

    cafebartablesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();  

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);

    try {

        cafebartables = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);


        for (int i = 0; i < cafebartables.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject c =cafebartables.getJSONObject(i);

            int tableId = c.getInt(TAG_TABLE_ID);
            int tableMarginLeft = c.getInt(TAG_MARGIN_LEFT);
            int tableMarginTop = c.getInt(TAG_MARGIN_TOP);
            int isFree = c.getInt(TAG_ISFREE);

            map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            map.put(TAG_TABLE_ID, tableId);
            map.put(TAG_MARGIN_LEFT, tableMarginLeft);
            map.put(TAG_MARGIN_TOP, tableMarginTop);
            map.put(TAG_ISFREE, isFree);

            cafebartablesList.add(map);


        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public  void printMap() {
    LoadMap ld = new LoadMap();

    ld.execute();

}

  public class LoadMap extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        updateJSONdata();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        length_txt =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.length_txt);
        length_txt.setText("the size is " +cafebartablesList.size());
    }
}
}
```

Otherwise, you could use something like Gson, create a POJO for your  cafebartablesList and  call

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(MyPojo.class, new MyDeserializer())
                .build();

MyPojo mp = gson.fromJson(json, MyPojo.class);
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is working! May i ask you something more? I want to retrieve some values from the database which represent the margin left  and margin top. I wan to use these values to generate some buttons. The printmap() method is for this process . But when i try to call it from onPostExecute app crashes..

Comment: Can you post a stack trace of the error you're getting during the crash